# Wrap text around image in outlook email through VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I am inserting a picture in Outlook, however this comes in half. When I do `WRAP SQUARE` then it become complete.

below is my code

```
Sub send1()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

Dim OLOOK As Outlook.Application

Set OLOOK = New Outlook.Application

Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem

Set omail = OLOOK.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

Dim CH As ChartObjects

Sheets("DL").Activate

LR1 = Sheets("DL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

LR2 = Sheets("DL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set emailRng = Worksheets("DL").Range("A2:A" & LR1)

Set emailRng1 = Worksheets("DL").Range("B2:B" & LR2)

For Each cl In emailRng

sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value

Next

For Each cl1 In emailRng1

sTo1 = sTo1 & ";" & cl1.Value

Next

tmp = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "Mypic.Bmp"

sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

sTo1 = Mid(sTo1, 2)

With omail

omail.To = sTo

omail.CC = sTo1

omail.Subject = Sheets("DL").Range("C2").Value

omail.HTMLBody = "<BR> " & " <style=border: none>" & "<table align=""center"">" & "<img src = '" & tmp & 

"' >"

omail.Display

End With

sh1.Pictures.Delete

sh.Activate

End Sub
```